# Reclaim root access - High Sierra

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra, sudo

I installed the Security Update 2020-001 for High Sierra. As a result of this, I am no longer able to use `sudo`. It just exits with the message

```
sudo: 4294967295: invalid value
```

As requested, here are the two `id` results:

```
> id $(whoami)
uid=501(my_username) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),
    61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),
    98(_lpadmin),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),33(_appstore),
    100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),
    398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)

> id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),4294967295(nogroup)
```

The culprit seems to be root being in the `nogroup` group which has an "invalid" id.

Having a look at `/etc/group`, the group has an id of `-1`.

```
> grep nogroup /etc/group 
nogroup:*:-1:
```

Figured out how to list group memberships on macOS:

```
> dscl . read /Groups/nogroup
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEFFFFFFFFF
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: -1
RealName:
 No Group
RecordName: nogroup
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups
```

The group does not have any members. And I don't seem to be able to find the `root` user on this system:

```
> dscl . read /Users/root
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14136 (eDSRecordNotFound)
```

New question: How do I remove `root` from the `nogroup`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While trying to enable the root user, I got the error

```
dsenableroot:: ***Failed to enable root user.
```

So I looked into that and found out thanks to an answer to [Why would dsenableroot NOT work on a 10.7.5 OSX Server?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257688/331081) that I had to check my root user in the file `/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/root.plist`.

Sadly, the file was missing. And this was the root cause of the problem: I didn't had a `root` user. After copying it from another macOS installation,

- `sudo` started working again
- `id` did no longer show the membership to `nogroup`
- the command `dscl . read /Users/root` said that it finally found a user
- and I was able to find `root` in the directory browser

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this is related with root being member of **No Group** (nogroup, groupids: 4294967295 and -1!).

My root user was enabled before running the Security Update 2020-001 for High Sierra. I didn't encounter this problem.

Your question and additional details suggest that your root user wasn't enabled.

To follow the steps below you probably have to enable root first in Directory Utility > Edit > Enable Root User!

To remove root from the group **No Group** you have to open Directory Utility and unlock it:

[image]

Hit Directory Editor and navigate to **Groups** in node **/Local/Default**

Choose **No Group** and remove root from GroupMembership and FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000 (= root) from GroupMembers.

[image]

A reboot is not necessary.

---

I tested this the other way round by adding root/FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000 to the respective attributs.

With root being member of **No Group** I get the following result executing some `sudo ...` command:

```
host:~ user$ sudo ls
sudo: 4294967295,701,33,98,100,204,250,395,398,399: invalid value
```

After removing root from **No Group** `sudo ...` works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spend on composing this answer. It is really appreciated. It didn't solved my problem, but hopefully someone else problem. Will compose an answer on how I solved my problem. It needed some inspiration from another one of your answers here :). +1